# Proving $\left(5\left(\sum^x_{n=0}10^n\right)+1\right)^2-\left(4\left(\sum^x_{n=0}10^n\right)+1\right)^2=\sum^{2x}_{n=0}10^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem says:

> Assuming $x\ge1$, prove that:
>   $$556^2-445^2=111111$$
>   $$5556^2-4445^2=11111111$$
>   $$.$$
>   $$.$$
>   $$.$$
>   $$\left(5\left(\sum^x_{n=0}10^n\right)+1\right)^2-\left(4\left(\sum^x_{n=0}10^n\right)+1\right)^2=\sum^{2x}_{n=0}10^n$$

I expanded it and simplified and at last I got this:

$$9 \left(\sum^x_{n=0}10^n\right)^2+2\left(\sum^x_{n=0}10^n\right)=\sum^{2x}_{n=0}10^n$$

Now proving this last equation is equivalent to proving the general case.

Comment: And I am not professional in using $\sum$ .

Comment: It is true for $x \ge 1$

Comment: I think it doesn't now deserve a down-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In
$9 \left(\sum^x_{n=0}10^n\right)^2+2\left(\sum^x_{n=0}10^n\right)?\sum^{2x}_{n=0}10^n$,
use
$\sum_{k=0}^m x^k
=\dfrac{x^{m+1}-1}{x-1}
$.

$\sum^x_{n=0}10^n
=\dfrac{10^{x+1}-1}{9},
$
and
$\sum^{2x}_{n=0}10^n
=\dfrac{10^{2x+1}-1}{9}
$
so your left side is

$\begin{array}\\
9(\dfrac{10^{x+1}-1}{9})^2
+2\dfrac{10^{x+1}-1}{9}
&=\dfrac{(10^{x+1}-1)^2+2(10^{x+1}-1)}{9}\\
&=\dfrac{10^{2x+2}-2\ 10^{x+1}+1+2(10^{x+1}-1)}{9}\\
&=\dfrac{10^{2x+2}-1}{9}\\
\end{array}
$

and the right side is
$\dfrac{10^{2x+1}-1}{9}$,
which is not the same.

However,
if you change your right side to
$\sum^{2x+1}_{n=0}10^n$,
then they *are* the same.

Comment: so the right side of the statement isn't true? should it be what you said?

Comment: @BlueSky Yeah, it looks like you set up the sums wrong; notice that $\sum_{n=0}^x 10^n$ is $\underbrace{11\ldots 11}_{x+1 \text{ times}}$ - as the right hand side needs twice as many $1$'s, you need $\sum_{n=0}^{2x+1} 10^n$ which is $\underbrace{11\ldots 11}_{2x+2 \text{ times}}$

Answer (score 1):

You can't prove this as it is not true.

Take $x=0$ for example, thus you get:

$9(10^0)^2+2(10^0)=10^{2*0}$

$9+2=1$

which is clearly not true.

Comment: Sorry . edited.

Comment: It is true for $x \ge 1$

Answer (score 1):

Use the difference of two squares identity, $a^{2}-b^{2}=(a-b)(a+b)$.
In your examples, $a-b=11\dots11$ and $a+b=10\dots 01$ (dots represent ones in the first case and zeroes in the second). Can you deduce the result?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^x 10^n = \dfrac{10^{x+1}-1}{10-1}=\dfrac{10^{x+1}-1}{9}.\tag{1}
$$

Then
$$9 \left(\sum^x_{n=0}10^n\right)^2+2\left(\sum^x_{n=0}10^n\right) \\
= 9 \dfrac{(10^{x+1}-1)^2}{81}+2\dfrac{10^{x+1}-1}{9} \\
= \dfrac{10^{2x+2}-2\cdot 10^{x+1}+1}{9}+\dfrac{2\cdot 10^{x+1}-2}{9} \\
=  \dfrac{10^{2x+2}-1}{9} = (see (1) ) = \sum_{n=0}^{2x+1} 10^n.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Though your method is probably workable, I'm not sure how you would proceed with it. What I would do is to notice that
$$10^n=1\underbrace{00\ldots 00}_{n\text{ zeros}}$$
so
$$10^n-1=\underbrace{99\ldots 99}_{n\text{ nines}}$$
and
$$\frac{10^n-1}{9}=\underbrace{11\ldots 11}_{n\text{ ones}}.$$
(You could get this by a formula for geometric sums too, but I like this way more). Thus you can write the equation as:
$$\left(5\cdot \frac{10^n-1}9+1\right)^2-\left(4\cdot \frac{10^n-1}9+1\right)^2=\frac{10^{2n}-1}9$$
and the rest should be straightforwards algebra.